# HTML + React: Radio button stuck on the one initially set as "checked"

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, reactjs

I have a set of two radio buttons one of which is checked when the page is loaded. It appears that I can't change it to the second one. The HTML is build by reactjs if that matters. The markup on chrome looks like:

```
<fieldset data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1">
<label for="coop-radio-btn" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0">To a Cooperative</span>
    <input type="radio" name="requestOnBehalfOf" value="coop" id="coop-radio-btn" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.1">
</label>
<label for="union-radio-btn" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.1">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.0">Additional Request</span>
    <input type="radio" name="requestOnBehalfOf" value="union" checked="" id="union-radio-btn" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1">
</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You should share your react component code as well. You are probably using controlled components  which reflect the value of `value` prop instead of user input:  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this was that React was making the `input`s controlled components because the values for each input are set from the server side.

Quoting from [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28315332/1242842):

If you add a `value={whatever}` property to the input, which makes it a controlled component, *then* it is read-only uness you add an `onChange` handler that updates the value of `whatever`. From [the React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-controlled-components):

> **Why Controlled Components?**
>
> Using form components such as `<input>` in React presents a challenge that is absent when writing traditional form HTML. For example, in HTML:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" name="title" value="Untitled" />
> ```
>
> This renders an input *initialized* with the value, `Untitled`. When the user updates the input, the node's value *property* will change. However, `node.getAttribute('value')` will still return the value used at initialization time, `Untitled`.
>
> Unlike HTML, React components must represent the state of the view at any point in time and not only at initialization time. For example, in React:
>
> ```
> render: function() {
>   return <input type="text" name="title" value="Untitled" />;
> }
> ```
>
> Since this method describes the view at any point in time, the value of the text input should *always* be `Untitled`.

The simplest solution I found is to add `onChange={function(){}}` to the `input`s.

Comment: I'm adding my 2c here in case someone else has the same issue. If you do everything by the book but it still doesn't work, check if there's `e.preventDefault()` call in your change handler and remove it.

Answer (score 18):

**update**
"the react way" of doing that is to add the `defaultChecked={true}` to the needed input. Other ways are listed below.

I actually faced the same situation. What I did was to find the `input` tag in the [`componentDidMount` lifecycle method](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) of the parent React component and set the `checked` attribute then.

If we speak about vanilla JS you can find the first radio input using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector). Like so:

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.getDOMNode().querySelector('[type="radio"]').checked = "checked";
    },
    render: function(){
        //your render here
    }
});
```

If you use jQuery, this can be done like this:

```
...
    $(this.getDOMNode()).find('[type="radio"]').eq(0).prop("checked", true);
...
```

Comment: Also I found a far better solution in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750864/conditionally-setting-html-attributes-in-react-js). Simply saying `defaultChecked={true}` on the needed input does the needed thing "the react way"

Comment: On the bottom of the answer it says "Side note: avoid defaultChecked/defaultValue and use checked/value with onChange instead." Have you seen that?

Comment: Yes, I have. Also I have seen the `console.info`'s from the React team that says _Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`_.

Comment: I hit a similar issue last week. In my situation the controlled radio component's `checked` prop was updated as expected on click (as shown by the React debugger in Chrome) but the checkbox I was looking at was using a custom radio created with CSS and, surprisingly, the radio had a `zIndex` set to `-1` which causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I used to have similar problem.

Use `defaultChecked` prop for (and only for) first render, and give an `onChange` function to handle value changes.

I found a very good example for different `input` types here: http://bl.ocks.org/insin/raw/082c0d88f6290a0ea4c7/

Answer (score 4):

Use `defaultChecked` like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="temperature" value="hot" defaultChecked={true}/> Hot
<input type="radio" name="temperature" value="warm" /> Warm
```